How to pass golang gin sesssion to next.js
Using
Next.js v14.2.3
App Router
I am following gin-contrib cookie-based sessions documentation, to increment a session count
    // This is the backend golang code
    ...
    cookieStore := sessions.NewCookieStore([]byte("secret"))
    router.Use(
        sessions.Sessions("mysession", cookieStore),
    )

    router.GET("incr", func(c *gin.Context) {
        session := sessions.Default(c)
        c.Header("Content-Type", "application/json")

        var count int
        v := session.Get("count")
        if v == nil {
            count = 0
        } else {
            count = v.(int)
            count++
        }
        session.Set("count", count)
        session.Save()
        c.JSON(200, gin.H{"count": count})
    })
    ...

This works using postman I can see the cookie session in the response and the counter increments with each request. (But I notice curl includes header and a cookie mysession)
curl --location 'localhost:8080/incr' \
--header 'Cookie: mysession=someLongKey='

Should I be setting this header with my fetch request? And how do I get the someLongKey value to send with the request?
Right now, when I try to send this request using fetch in next.js project.
        // this is the frontend next.js code
        const resp = await fetch(`${process.env.BACKEND}/incr`)
        const res = await Promise.all([resp.json()])
        console.log("this is the res ",res)

The output does not increment as expected,
this is the res  [ { count: 0 } ]
 POST /incr 200 in 16ms
this is the res  [ { count: 0 } ]
 POST /incr 200 in 17ms
this is the res  [ { count: 0 } ]
 POST /incr 200 in 15ms
this is the res  [ { count: 0 } ]

and when I use the browser developer tools I can not see the cookie in the response.

Does this answer your question? How to include cookies with fetch request in Nextjs

Thanks @Brits! I tried this, but still no success. The comments say this should be working with Next.js App router. I am updating my question with those specific details, along with other observations from making this request successfully with postman.

Using mdn web docs, updating the js code
...
const resp = await fetch(`${process.env.BACKEND}/incr`)
const cookie = resp.headers.get("set-cookie")
console.log("this is the cookie ",cookie)
...

the response cookies are seen in the headers.
using this cookie and fetching again
        const resp = await fetch(`${process.env.BACKEND}/incr`,{
            headers:{
                Cookie:`cookieValueFromAbove`
            }
        })

Now I am able to see the counter increment as expected
this is the res  [ { count: 1 } ]
 POST /incr 200 in 58ms
this is the res  [ { count: 2 } ]
 POST /incr 200 in 52ms

Putting it all together using the next.js cookie and headers documentation. Lead me to create middleware.ts
...
export default async function middleware(request:NextRequest){
    const response = NextResponse.next();
    const cookieStore = cookies()
    let cookie = cookieStore.get('set-cookie')
    let header = ""
    if(!cookie) {
        console.log("we need to fetch from gin and get cookie from response")
        const initialPromise = await fetch(`${process.env.BACKEND}/incr`)
        header = initialPromise.headers.get('set-cookie')
        console.log("this is the response cookie",header)
    } else {
        console.log("Finally the cookie",cookie)
        response.headers.set('set-cookie',cookie.value)
    }

    return response
}
...

Updating the function in scr/app/lib/actions.ts
...
export async function incr(...){
        const initialHeaders = headers().get('set-cookie')
        const initialPromise = await fetch(`${process.env.BACKEND}/incr`,{
            headers:{
                cookie:initialHeaders
            },
        })

        const updatedHeaders = initialPromise.headers.get('set-cookie')
        cookies().set("set-cookie",updatedHeaders)
}

The output
this is the res  [ { count: 43 } ]
 POST /incr 200 in 58ms
this is the res  [ { count: 44 } ]
 POST /incr 200 in 26ms
this is the res  [ { count: 45 } ]
 POST /incr 200 in 23ms
this is the res  [ { count: 46 } ]
 POST /incr 200 in 22ms
this is the res  [ { count: 47 } ]

